# PHP: Accepting a base 64 encoded image and saving it to JPG

Tags: php, image

I think I am missing a step to take in a base64 encoded image and convert to a jpg and save it. So this i what I am doing:

```
$data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $request->all()['imagePreviewUrls'][0]));
$source = imagecreatefromstring($data);
$saved = $this->compressImage($source, '../../frontend/public/productimages/__test.jpg');
```

compressImage() looks like this:

```
private function compressImage(string $sourceImage, string $destination) {
        $info = getimagesize($sourceImage);

        if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceImage);
        } else if ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($sourceImage);
        } else if ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($sourceImage);
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Image type not supported.');
        }

        return imagejpeg($image, $destination, 80);
    }
```

From $data I get an image in which I can do this to save the image:

```
file_put_contents('../../frontend/public/productimages/what.png', $data);
```

But how could I take the base64 encoded image and then convert, compress, and save the jpg?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.  `imagecreatefromstring` will give you a `GD` (image) object.  `imagejpeg` will then save that to a file.  What problem are you trying to solve here?  Why are you checking the MIME type in `compressImage`?

Comment: Well what if my image i upload is a png or a gif? do i not have to convert it?

Comment: You don't need to convert it.  `imagecreatefromstring` takes care of that.  From there, you can use `imagejpeg` to save it as a jpeg, regardless of what format it was in the beginning.

Comment: oh thats awesome, never knew that, thanks!

Comment: You might have a good reason for doing it, but you may not need to base64 encode the image file. You could just send it directly in a form or API call. base64 encoding something makes it MUCH bigger. If you're uploading a base64 encoded image, it will take a lot longer to send.

Comment: what are alternative options then?

Comment: what are alternative options then? As I basically use new FileReader() in js to get that base64 image and upload it

Answer (score 1):

When you use [`imagecreatefromstring()`](https://php.net/imagecreatefromstring), you're returned a [GD](https://php.net/gd) (image) object.  From there you can use any of the GD functions on the object.  GD automatically detects the image type and loads it.

So, to save it as a JPEG, you can just use [`imagejpeg()`](https://php.net/imagejpeg), regardless of what the original image format was.

```
$data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $request->all()['imagePreviewUrls'][0]));

$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
imagejpeg($image, '../../frontend/public/productimages/__test.jpg', 80);
```